# Lemma relating to alpha equivalence of lambda terms

Tags: lambda-calculus

From [Type Theory and Formal Proof, An Introduction](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=orsrBQAAQBAJ&hl=en_US&pg=GBS.PR2) by Rob Nederpelt and Herman Geuvers:

Lemma 1.7.1 Let $M_{1} =_{\alpha} N_{1}$ and $M_{2} =_{\alpha} N_{2}$. Then also:

(1) $M_{1}N_{1} =_{\alpha} M_{2}N_{2}$,

(2) $\lambda x . M_{1} =_{\alpha} \lambda x . M_{2}$,

(3) $M_{1}[x := N_{1}] =_{\alpha} M_{2}[x := N_{2}]$.

Why does this hold? There does not seem to be a stated connection between $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ or $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$.

Comment: It is just a typo. The hypothesis of lemma 1.7.1 should be $M_1 =_\alpha M_2$ and $N_1 =_\alpha N_2$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!